# Getting blank Values using Javascript from Input Element

Tags: javascript, html

So, I was working on a simple Form validation. But after entering the value when I try to get the value from the input element in the console using JavaScript, it is returning blank.

Where am I going wrong:

Here is the code:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("fName").value;
var y = document.getElementById("lName").value;
var z = document.getElementById("emailId").value;

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
  console.log(x);
}
```

```html
<h1 class="jumbotron">Simple Form Validation</h1>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <form>
    <label>First Name: <input type="text" value="" id="fName" placeholder="ex: Shubham"></label><br />
    <label>Second Name: <input id="lName" value="" type="text" placeholder="ex: Bhatt"></label><br />
    <label>Email Id: <input id="emailId" value="" type="alphanumeric" placeholder="ex: abc@gmail.com"></label> <br />
    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="myFunction()">
    <p id="demo"></p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code gets the values of the fields **once**, when the page first loads. Move those first three lines of code inside the function.

Comment: Thanks, it worked

Answer (score 1):

```js
    /*
    var x = document.getElementById("fName").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("lName").value;
    var z = document.getElementById("emailId").value;
    */
        function myFunction(){
            var x = document.getElementById("fName").value;
            var y = document.getElementById("lName").value;
            var z = document.getElementById("emailId").value;
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
            console.log(x);
        }
```

```html
<h1 class="jumbotron">Simple Form Validation</h1>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <form>  
        <label>First Name: <input type="numeric" value="" id="fName" placeholder="ex: Shubham"></label><br />
        <label>Second Name: <input id="lName" value="" type="text" placeholder="ex: Bhatt"></label><br />
        <label>Email Id: <input id="emailId" value="" type="alphanumeric" placeholder="ex: abc@gmail.com"></label> <br />
        <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="myFunction()">
    <p id="demo"></p>
    </form>
</div>
```

Move variable

Global -> Local

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the values outside the function, in other words, you try to get the values of the input fields before you enter anything there. Try this instead of your javascript

```
<script>

        function myFunction(){
            var x = document.getElementById("fName").value;
            var y = document.getElementById("lName").value;
            var z = document.getElementById("emailId").value;
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
            console.log(x);
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are extracting the values when the documents get ready. But you have to get the value when users submit the form.So you need to get the values inside the `function` try using this:

```
    function myFunction(){
         var x = document.getElementById("fName").value;
       var y = document.getElementById("lName").value;
        var z = document.getElementById("emailId").value;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
        console.log(x);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You only querying your values once as you load the page. What you can do is to query the fields and value inside your function. Or better: only check the values in your function and leave the `getElementById` still outside, like this:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("fName");
var y = document.getElementById("lName");
var z = document.getElementById("emailId");

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x.value;
  console.log(x.value);
}
```

```html
<h1 class="jumbotron">Simple Form Validation</h1>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <form>
    <label>First Name: <input type="text" value="" id="fName" placeholder="ex: Shubham"></label><br />
    <label>Second Name: <input id="lName" value="" type="text" placeholder="ex: Bhatt"></label><br />
    <label>Email Id: <input id="emailId" value="" type="alphanumeric" placeholder="ex: abc@gmail.com"></label> <br />
    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="myFunction()">
    <p id="demo"></p>
  </form>
</div>
```