# Firebase web auth: The email address is badly formatted

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to make a simple web auth page using firebase auth but getting this error everytime

```
//HTML: 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.2.0/firebase.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="email" id="txtEmail"><br/>
    <br/>
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="txtPass"><br/><br/>
    <button id="loginButton" onclick="validate();">Login</button>
    <script src="auth2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

//JS File

```
// Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY",
    authDomain: "YOUR_DOMAIN",
    databaseURL: "YOUR_DB_URL",
    projectId: "PROJECT_ID",
    storageBucket: "STORAGE",
    messagingSenderId: "SENDER_ID"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

    var email = document.getElementById("txtEmail").value;
    var pass = document.getElementById("txtPass").value;


    function validate(){
        const auth = firebase.auth();
        const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
        promise.catch(function(error){
            console.log("Got a error", error);
        })
    }
```

I get this error in console:

```
Fr {code: "auth/invalid-email", message: "The email address is badly formatted."}
```

Comment: Seems like you have to format the email address differently.

Comment: Move your two `var email` and `var pass` lines down **inside** the `validate` function

Comment: please check network tab and see the bottom section and it will show you the data passed and check the email from there

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45896062/getting-blank-values-using-javascript-from-input-element

Comment: @Phil Thank you so much. it worked :)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha how it worked ? Kindly share the solution !